# Error uploading actions to Gactions ( Google Assistant )

Tags: google-assistant-sdk, google-assist-api

I am receiving the following error on uploading the actions.json to gactions using Windows as well as Linux.

```
ERROR: Failed to update the app for the Assistant
ERROR: The caller does not have permission
2019/04/13 13:56:47 Server did not return HTTP 200
```

Account used to upload action is same as the one used to create project.
I am able to get the verification code and once I paste back in terminal to authenticate it gives the above error.

Can someone please guide what is to be done exactly, I am using the below guide on google 
https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/guides/library/python/extend/custom-actions

Comment: You need to take a look at what account and project that gactions is linked to, as one or both do not seem to be correct to upload the action package.

Comment: Account is same as the one created project with but it still shows the same error..or is there any other way to create actions for google assistant?

Comment: If you want to create an Action then you may want to look at Dialogflow, as the documentation you link to does not show you how to build an action.